# How fetch data from multiple database into tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am concern on finding the error on my code. I have tried other code but the error keeps appearing. All I want is to retrieve my selected data into the table. Please help!

```
<?php
echo"<table>";
$sql="select products.product_title,orders.order_id,products.product_price, cart.qty from products, cart where products.product_id=cart.p_id";

$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>"."<center>" .$row[0]."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>" .$row[1]."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row[2]."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$row[3]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; } 
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

Comment: use join to select from multiple tables

Comment: what error do you get?? If you are not able to see error then enable debug mode. Read http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-debug-in-php

Comment: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ..." thats the error I get. i assume tha this error appears because there is something wrong on the syntax

Answer (score 0):

Check your Query, you have selected **orders.order_id** which is not present on selected tables, and add a condition which will join the table **order**.

```
SELECT products.product_title,orders.order_id,products.product_price, cart.qty 
FROM products, cart 
WHERE products.product_id=cart.p_id
```

Comment: add a condition which will join the table how can i do that? i know conditioning if there are 2 tables but in terms of multiple tables i do not know how. can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing in right way, but use mysqli instead of mysql, it is removed from php7 and deprecated from php. here is the query,(I am taking help from Eyy's answer)

```
SELECT tbl_a.column1 , tbl_a.column2 
   tbl_b.column1 , tbl_b.column2, 
   tbl_c.column1,  tbl_c.column2
FROM  tbl_a INNER JOIN tbl_b ON 
tbl_a.commonfield=tbl_b.commonfield
INNER JOIN tbl_c ON
tbl_a.commonfield=tbl_c.commonfield
```

Change your table and column name as per your requirement.

Comment: can you do the syntax of an multiple table (more than 2). I know how to do that, its just that if i am calling more than 2 tables i don't know how to condition them

Comment: @PatriciaErikaDelaCruz did you use mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: @PatriciaErikaDelaCruz Please see answer I have changed